# Where to put code thats used on many views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I have this piece of code in my **_header.html.erb** partial which is used by **application.html.erb**.

```
<% current_user.achievements.each do |achievement| %>
  <li><%= link_to achievement.header_string, polymorphic_path(achievement.achievementable) %></li>
<% end %>
```

*current_user.achievements* seems more appropriete to put in a controller instead? But im not sure where to put it, this is similar to the achievements in the header here on Stack Overflow. This code will be used in all views if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I don't see anything wrong using `current_user.achievements` in your views as it **will call up current users achievements once and then rails [caches that query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching) result for you**.*

*If you really want to put it somewhere then **application controller** is the place to be*

```
def achievements
  @acheivements = current_user.achievements
end
```

then use before filter on whatever action you want it to set

```
before_filter :achievements, only: [:your_methods]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in the application controller with a helper method.

```
helper_method :achievements

def acheivements(current_user)
  current_user.achievements.each do |achievement| 
   <do stuff>
end
```

you can then call it from anywhere because all of your controllers inherit from application controller.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR leave it as it is

Actually your question could be answered in two ways:

1. If you are referring to the view code (i.e. build the list), then this is what partials are meant for. And by placing it in the _header partial you do the right thing.
2. If you are referring to the call of `current_user.achievements` and you feel that the view would be the wrong place for triggering a database call I would say: yes and no. This is the point where the strict MVC logic is a bit less strict. I would never clutter my controllers with filter methods or instance variables for such a case. To my mind it is perfectly fine to let the views decide which properties of objects and potentially which related objects the need to display. A controller involvement in that story could cover something like access control on a field level (by setting achievements to [] in not-auhorized case). I also think that your version is nice, readable and explicit code.